# Pentaho Case study or use case

Tags: etl, pentaho, business-intelligence, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I got a job opportunity as an ETL developer, but they told me show a Case study or use case of Pentaho data integration using spoon. I am very new to this field. Could you please suggest me a place where I can start my case study. I have no idea how can I make a case study in Pentaho data integration ( spoon).
I have explored almost all functions(transformation, flows, input, output objects) in Pentaho data integration using spoon. Now, i do not have any idea how can i gather all objects to create a use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any dataset which is available for free online, for example https://data.world/datasets/travel

Treat it as a source and try to build dimensions and facts, with the goal to serve the sales dashboard analysis or customer analysis, which typical has month-quarter-yearly view of the data and key indicators, for example take sample travel data set from the link above and try to create the data-warehouse to serve this report/dashboard requirement in background.

[image]

I think this is a good idea to have some exposure.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it out. Thanks again